# Writing a function for Ramanujan nested radicals

Tags: r, loops, nested-loops

I am writing a function for Ramanujan nested radicals in R. Ramanujan nested radicals equation is following:
[image]

I need to take n as only input argument. I am not sure how to code it in R.

Comment: As you have written the formula, it is an infinite nested radical.  How do you intend to stop for a finite n?

Comment: I need to ask the value of  n. Say n = 5 then this series should be like:
 (Sqrt(1+2 Sqrt(1+3 Sqrt (1+4 Sqrt(1+5)) @G5W

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do it

```
RNR <- function(N) Reduce(function(n, x) sqrt(1 + n * x), 2:N, 1, right = TRUE)

sapply(2:10, RNR) #only valid for N>1
[1] 1.732051 2.236068 2.559830 2.755053 2.867103 2.929173 2.962723 2.980554 2.989920
```

Comment: How to get one final value? 
f = sum(sapply(2:10,RNR)

Comment: No, RNR(n) is the final value.  Just set n to be large (in sapply or a loop, for example) to get the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Using recursion:

```
ram <- Vectorize(function(n, r = 1) ifelse(n <= 1, r, ram(n - 1, sqrt(1 + n*r))))
ram(1:5)
[1] 1.000000 1.732051 2.236068 2.559830 2.755053
```

Reaches the limit of 3 with machine precision somewhere around 50-60:

```
3 - ram(seq(10, 100, 10))
[1] 1.007964e-02 1.211940e-05 1.317704e-08 1.382006e-11 1.421085e-14 0.000000e+00
[7] 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
```

Comment: Thank you @jblood94